# Unity coordinates doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I'm very beginner in Unity so please forgive if, this questions isn't so hard to answer:) 
So, I have a text on a Canvas in the editor, it is okay, it's showing well on Scene editor and In Game as well. 
But, when I added two Sprites, which going to be the player and the enemy, the positions of these sprites are behave a bit weird.

The text position is: x: -293 y: 195, when I'm modifying the position of the text it works fine.

When I add the sprites to x:0 y:0 and x:1 y:1, in the scene editor they appear in the left bottom corner, but when I check in the game, they placed in the middle of the screen.

My question is why the coordinates and the positions are so different on Scene (grey) and on Game (blue) ?

[image: Sprites showed on Scene]
[image: Sprites showed in Game]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because initialized render mode of Canvas in Unity is "ScreenSpace - Overlay". So it is shown on too big area in scene. If you want to work only in view field of camera, in inspector just change render mode of Canvas to "ScreenSpace-Camera" and drag your MainCamera to RenderCamera in inspector. Even if you use ScreenSpace-Camera, coordinate system of RectTransform (UI Objects transform) is different than Transform (Normal game objects transform)

in this view, if you get closer to the left-down corner of your scene, you will see your main camera area and Sprites that are in correct positions.

I hope this helps.